# Create xml file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to send an xml file as an attachment in an email.

I have a json from which I will create an xml. My question is, can I just write a string of tags into a file and is it a valid xml file?

I am thinking about using template literals(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like

```
  const myXmlString =   `<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <TALLYREQUEST>${myVarsValue}</TALLYREQUEST>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY></BODY>
</HEADER>
</ENVELOPE>`
```

And write a file

```
 file.writeFileSync("./filesx.xml", myXmlString, function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Is this still valid xml file?

I am trying to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder which generated xml like this:

```
   var xml = builder.create('root')
  .ele('xmlbuilder')
    .ele('repo', {'type': 'git'}, 'git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git')
  .end({ pretty: true});
```

But I don't know how to write this into a file.

Can I just use the first method or should I use the xmlbuilder? Even if the first method is ok, can someone tell me how I an write its result to a file?

I tried this https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/issues/227 but I get an error saying

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?><root><example0/><example1/><example2/><example3/><example4/><example5/><example6/><example7/><example8/><example9/></root>
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
    at XMLStringifier.assertLegalChar (/Volumes/D/Vue admin node/card91_nodejs_boilerplate/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLStringifier.js:209:32)
    at XMLElement.element (/Volumes/D/Vue admin node/card91_nodejs_boilerplate/node_modules/xmlbuilder/lib/XMLNode.js:127:25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

> Can I just write a string of tags into a file and is it a valid xml file?

Yes, it is as long as your XML content is valid.
In your example, you may need to add XML prolog `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` to the beginning of your XML string. However, it is optional.

**Question 2**

> Can I just use the first method or should I use the xmlbuilder? Even if the first method is ok, can someone tell me how I an write its result to a file?

You should use xmlbuilder if the XML content is complex. When you call `end()` function your document is converted into a string. Therefore, you can use the write to file method in the first question to create the XML file.

```js
var xml = builder.create('root')
    .ele('xmlbuilder')
        .ele('repo', {'type': 'git'}, 'git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git')
    .end({ pretty: true});

file.writeFileSync("./filesx.xml", xml, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

You can read more about xmlbuilder functions here.
https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/wiki